# The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

hi i am new to spring security and i have just created my first app and it is working with default spring security login page but whenever i am using custom login page and using line `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>` in my jsp login page so it is showing following error

```
The absolute uri: [http://www.springframework.org/tags/form] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

also i copied this line from my spring-webmvc-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar/META-INF/spring-form.tld still it is showing same error.If i remove line `%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>` from jsp login page so it showing normal login page but not able validate username or password from **webSecurityConfig.java** file

**webSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("java").password("123").roles("EMPLOYEE");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("google").password("123").roles("manager");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/loginForm")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
    .permitAll();
}
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: no i am not using spring boot only spring mvc and spring security

Comment: Any update on this ? i have same issue now

Comment: yes @rinilnath i resolved the problem by replacing tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=\ with tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=\*.jar in tomcat9/catalina.properties

Comment: Thanks, in my case i solved by adding spring-taglib dependency to the pom.xml